# RcppArmadillo: Is there a way to keep names?

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

Consider the following code:

```
funSrc33a <- '
NumericVector A  = as<NumericVector>(in1);
return wrap(A);
'
funSrc33b <- '
using namespace arma;
vec A  = as<vec>(in1);
return wrap(A);
'
iFun33a <- cxxfunction(sig = signature(in1 = "numeric"), funSrc33a, plugin = "Rcpp")
iFun33b <- cxxfunction(sig = signature(in1 = "numeric"), funSrc33b, plugin = "RcppArmadillo")
foo = c("First" = 1, "Second" = 2)
iFun33a(foo)
iFun33b(foo)
```

The end result is:

```
> iFun33a(foo)
 First Second 
     1      2 
> iFun33b(foo)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
```

Is it possible to have armadillo keep the names from the input vector like Rcpp::NumericVector does? I would like the output of iFun33b to mirror iFun33a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R objects can have attributes. That is how row and column names are stored.

*Ex ante* Armadillo objects have nothing like that. You would need to add that.